# docker compose can not connect to postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, docker

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
server.port=8000
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "root"
      POSTGRES_DB: test

  lady:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: ./test/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      DB_USER: "postgres"
      DB_PASSWORD: "123"
      DB_TYPE: "postgres"
    command: ["java","-jar","test.jar"]
```

**logs error**

```
com.women.lady.LadyApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
                Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException
                    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
                        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
```

I can't connect to postgres or db when I run docker compose: **docker-compose up**

**Question**

How to connect db on docker-compose.
Please give me example.

Comment: First, can you add docker postgrs logs ? and also add to your yml file under `lady:`    the db_host  `DB_HOST:  db` , how is the container gonna know to which db container to connect if you didnt tell it the host ?

Comment: Does the db Start corretly? Cam you provide zur Liga?

Comment: I added DB_HOST: db under `lady:` already but it still error.

Comment: log error> Task :test com.women.lady.LadyApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
                Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException
                    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
                        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
1 test completed, 1 failed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.> Task :test FAILED